# Transformations to move corners further or closer

Tags: css, webkit, transform, css-transforms

I'm trying to rotate a plane from the top left corner so it will be placed further in space.

So far I only managed to move the whole right, left, top, or bottom planes further or closer in space, but not the corners themselves. 
I tried changing the `transform-origin` but it doesn't seem to be helping to achieve it. Using now `transform-origin: top left;`

Reproduction online:
https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/q3zvm9wt/5/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try the use of `rotate3d()` where you can specify the axe of roration, I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: Exactly that!! Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it! Here's the reproduction of what I wanted: 
https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/q3zvm9wt/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the use `rotate3d()` where you can easily adjust the axe of rotation to obtain the needed effect:

> The amount of rotation created by `rotate3d()` is specified by three `<number>`s and one `<angle>`. The `<number>`s represent the x-, y-, and z-coordinates of the vector denoting the axis of rotation. The `<angle>` represents the angle of rotation<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d)</sup>

```css
.section-wrapper {
  perspective: 614px;
}

.section {
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 60deg);
  ;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

html,
body,
.section-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section phase1">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```